# ida pro stack variables in hex view

Tags: ida

You have the IDA View and Hex View right. When on IDA View you select an instruction you can see the instruction selected in Hex View as well. However, if you select a "data instruction" like "Format          = dword ptr -10h" which is a stack variable, you don't see it in the hex view. It doesn't select the bytes corresponding to the variable definition. I mean I know the variable is going to be there in memory but somewhere on the hex view should tell me "hey allocate this stack variable" but it doesn't.

It's probably obvious by now, I'm a beginner in reverse engineering, I've been reading the book from http://beginners.re/ . While I do know some assembly and have been able to reverse simple things, I have these knowledge gaps I'd like to fill. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack variables live in the stack's address space, not in the module's address space. Thus, there's nothing that the Hex View could show you statically.

Comment: Ok so you have the text segment, data segment, bss segment. They all exist in the module's address space and get loaded into memory right? However in memory there are 2 more segments that don't exist in the module's space address, which is stack and heap. I thought the variables in the data segment(module's address space) were loaded to the stack, so I know where they come from, but what about these stack variables that aren't defined anywhere in the program, how do they end up in the stack? Thank you.

Comment: For each thread in the process, the operating system will create a region of memory for that thread's stack, so there can be multiple stack memory regions in a given process's address space. Similarly, the program's code may create multiple heap memory regions in the process's address space. The variables in the data segment are global variables (not stack variables); they are not automatically loaded onto the stack. Stack variables (also known as local function variables) are written to and read from the stack at runtime by the functions to which they belong.

Comment: I think I'm almost there. Here's a disassembled "hello world" program (only part of it)

"
...
Format= dword ptr -10h
...
mov     [esp+10h+Format], offset Format ; "hello world"
...
"


It uses "Format" twice, if I click on the "Format" near "offset" I'm redirected to the .rdata section.
However, there is this "Format" next to "10h+" that redirects me to stack variables. This is why I'm confused, you said that stack variables are written to and read from the stack at runtime.
So where is the instruction to write to the stack? "malloc" is runtime, but the instruction's in your code. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your example, IDA is using the same variable name (`Format`) for both a local stack variable and a global variable, hence the confusion. The `Format` in the `[]`s is for the local stack variable; the `Format` in `offset Format` is for the global variable in the .rdata section. I'd recommend renaming one of these `Format` variables in IDA to make it less confusing.

Comment: I know that...sorry I think I'm not explaining myself well. My "hello world" creates a stack variable in runtime. Ok. But where is the instruction to do so? Like I said, if I create
a variable in the heap using "malloc", I have the instruction in my code to do so. I have an instruction to create variables in the heap. I have instructions to create variables in the data segment(global variables).
My question is, where is the instruction to create the variable in the stack? You're telling me there is no such instruction in the module's address space, then well, where is it then? Thank you.

Comment: In the function prologue there will usually be an instruction that reserves the stack space needed for local variables. E.g. `sub esp, 10h` (to reserve 16 bytes) or `push ecx` (to reserve 4 bytes). Sometimes the compiler overlays local variables on the stack space occupied by function parameters, if it doesn't need those anymore (i.e. when they're past their live ranges). Then there might not be an explicit reservation for locals.

Comment: I was just going to say that. I ran my "hello world" on Cheat Engine and there isn't any "Format          = dword ptr -10h", but there is the "sub esp, 10h" indeed(just like there is in IDA). And the "mov"? It shows as "mov     [esp], test1.exe+11C0", no "Format" or "10h". I think IDA just shows that line to show the user that a variable is being allocated in the stack, but it's not an actual instruction. It would be better if IDA just commented the "sub esp, 10h" line saying "hey this line reserves stack space" instead of inserting a ghost instruction to explain that. Thank you.

Comment: The `Format = dword ptr -10h` is not an instruction, ghost or otherwise. It's a declaration that allows it to put a meaningful name to stack references, even though the stack pointer keeps fluctuating (at least in 32-bit mode). IDA does it by picking a fixed frame of reference (usually the return address) and accounting for the current value of ESP with a literal number, e.g. `push [esp+4+foobar]` if the 'logical' stack pointer has a value of 4 currently. That way one and the same stack location always gets the same name; otherwise it would be `[esp]` in one place and `[esp+10h]` in another.